# Running app on two devices but one crashes

Tags: android, window, memory-leaks

Really need some help here. I have tested my app on several devices and have a demo tomorrow.

I have a HTC desire C, exactly the same as one I've been testing on down to same software version. When I install my app on the new device it crashes when trying to load a loading dialog on the following line:

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LocationSearchForPeople.this,
                    "Loading Results", "Please wait...", true);
```

Below is the output from my logcat. I'm completely stumped here how it could not work between two devices that are the same. I hope that it could be a problem with the device?

```
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178): Activity com.capgemini.findme.LocationSearchForPeople has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41014cb0 that was originally added here
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.capgemini.findme.LocationSearchForPeople has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41014cb0 that was originally added here
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:396)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:372)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:320)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:152)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:557)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:301)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at com.capgemini.findme.LocationSearchForPeople$1.onClick(LocationSearchForPeople.java:81)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14330)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-06 19:23:05.353: E/WindowManager(3178):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 19:23:11.259: D/dalvikvm(3178): GC_CONCURRENT freed 777K, 15% free 5238K/6115K, paused 3ms+6ms
02-06 19:23:14.402: D/AndroidRuntime(3178): Shutting down VM
02-06 19:23:14.402: W/dalvikvm(3178): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa8228)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178): crash in the same process: main
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:752)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:472)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:163)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:348)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:139)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-06 19:23:14.402: E/AndroidRuntime_2_crash(3178):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you have the portion of the code that would potentially make it crash? seems like the cause is that one of your thread is crashing.

Comment: @EHarpham When it occur when you change the orientation of mobile when progress bar is spinner is displayed??

Comment: Could it be some settings on the new device?

Comment: @CChi The code is quite complicated and calls several functions and threads. It works fine on 2 other devices however which is why im confused...

Comment: @EHarpham tell me when it occur..

Comment: @Javier THANKS FOR BREAKING THE POST

Comment: It occurs when trying to send a HTTP post request to sql server via php

Comment: can you share the full logcat?

Comment: make sure you don't have exception from the thread by checking more than ERROR level. you might see the exception in yellow

Comment: one thing it might occur when you are doing http request and mean while you change the orientation of mobile.???Check this let me know??

Comment: full logcat http://pastebin.com/qR7a5k2Q

Comment: Any difference in android version? are you making network request in UI thread?

Comment: Android version exactly the same. Network requests are running in Asynctask

Comment: what is at line 183 in GPSTracker.java? it is causing an exception..

Comment: Damn thanks for some reason my code is crashing when i try and get a GPS signal

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, your `LocationSearchForPeople` activity is shutting down, but `ProgressDialog` is still active. That's why Android complains about leaked window.
You need to dismiss active dialog before leaving the activity which started the `ProgressDialog`.

You can override the `onDestroy` method in your `LocationSearchForPeople`activity and call `dialog.dismiss()` there

Comment: I have tried adding this code in the onDestroy but there is no change. I am unsure why this would work on one device but not another?